# Why does the current directory not change after executing script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, directory, cd-command

A script is executed from the shell as `./oximeter`.

The script, `oximeter`, has 5 commands:

```bsh
python3 ~/Documents/oximeter/3211ipod.py
ls -l
pwd
cd ~/Documents/oximeter/
pwd
```

The python script runs as expected.  I would like the script to change the directory as shown in command #4.  When control is returned to the user, the directory remains unchanged.

The second `pwd` returns the desired directory, however when control is returned to the user, `pwd` indicates that the directory is not `~/Documents/oximeter`.

Why is this and is there a 'stronger' command that changes the target directory for the user?

This is in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

because you only tell python3 to run the .py script **from** a directory and you would have to `cd` there first

(e.g. in the script :) `cd $(dirname ~/myfolder/myscript.py) ;python3 myscript.py`

---

you can get the location of your python script in python with:

```
print('abspath:     ', os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('abs dirname: ', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/os_getcwd.htm